# Check two arrays in google apps script and save common items in a new array

Tags: google-apps-script

I have

```
arr1 = [aaa,bbb,ccc,ttt,yyy]
arr2 = [abc,ttt,def,hij,ew,y,uuu]
```

I want the same/common items in both arrays to be saved in a new array

```
Same_items = [ttt]
```

I have tried using

```
var Same_items = [];
  for(let i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
    if(arr2.indexOf(arr1[i]) !== -1) {
      Same_items.push(arr1[i]);
    }
  }
```

also,

```
var Same_itema = [];
Same_items = arr1.filter(item => arr2.includes(item));
```

I not getting the desired output. I am not doing it right. Please guide

Thank you!

Comment: I think that if `const arr1 = ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ttt", "yyy"];` and `const arr2 = ["abc", "ttt", "def", "hij", "ew", "y", "uuu"];` are the sample input values, `Same_items` of `Same_items = arr1.filter(item => arr2.includes(item));` will return the value of `["ttt"]`. So, can you provide the detail of `I not getting the desired output.`? For example, how about `console.log(["aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ttt", "yyy"].filter(item => ["abc", "ttt", "def", "hij", "ew", "y", "uuu"].includes(item)))`? Also, I think that your above script returns `["ttt"]`.

Comment: I am sorry, I missed to check the output closely. Thank you @Tanaike- san

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm writing this answer as a community wiki since the solution was provided by @[Tanaike](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7108653/tanaike)-san and the OP (@[Alicia Stone](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20357303/alicia-stone)) in the comments section.

Both options:

```
  const arr1 = ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ttt", "yyy"];
  const arr2 = ["abc", "ttt", "def", "hij", "ew", "y", "uuu"];

  Same_items = arr1.filter(item => arr2.includes(item));

  Logger.log(Same_items)
```

and

```
  const arr1 = ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ttt", "yyy"];
  const arr2 = ["abc", "ttt", "def", "hij", "ew", "y", "uuu"];

  console.log("second option: " + arr1.filter(item => arr2.includes(item)))
```

will return the same/common items in both arrays.